# Testing a Dynamic Button View

Tags: swift, swiftui, xctest, xctestcase

I've inherited a SwiftUI codebase and am attempting to write some UITests for it.

Now, I'm still catching up to speed with writing Swift and SwiftUI code, so I'm not sure of the legitimacy of the design pattern being utilized. There's essentially an initial view, that starts with an initial `@State` and begins to pass it down from there into later view through the `@Binding` tag.

Due to Swift's UI testing requiring an Accessibility label, the button below is causing me a bit of a headache. For a handful of views, there is only ever one `BottomTextButton` with the content within it dynamically changing based on the case statement and the view we are viewing.

```swift
    struct TextButton {
        enum ButtonType {
            case signUp
            case logIn
        }
    }

    //View for the bottom text button in the signup / login flow.
    struct BottomTextButton: View {

        @Binding var loginSignupScreen: LoginSignupFlow.ScreenType
        @Binding var bottomTextButton: TextButton.ButtonType
        @Binding var signUpCTA: String
        @Binding var transitonBackward: Bool
        @Binding var buttonAccessibilityLabel: String

        var body: some View {

            Button(action: {

                    switch self.bottomTextButton {
                    case .logIn:
                        self.transitonBackward = false
                        self.loginSignupScreen = .logIn
                        self.bottomTextButton = .signUp
                        self.signUpCTA = "Text me a code"
                        self.buttonAccessibilityLabel = "logIn"

                    case .signUp:
                        self.transitonBackward = true
                        self.loginSignupScreen = .signUp
                        self.bottomTextButton = .logIn
                        self.buttonAccessibilityLabel = "signUp"
                    }

            }) {
                VStack(spacing: 0) {
                    bottomTextButtonFunction()
                }
                .padding([.bottom], 20)
                .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
            }
            .accessibility(label: Text("\(self.buttonAccessibilityLabel)"))

        }

        func bottomTextButtonFunction() -> AnyView {
           switch bottomTextButton {
                case .signUp: return AnyView(SignUpButtonView())
                case .logIn: return AnyView(LogInButtonView())
            }
        }
    }

    //Sign Up Button
    struct SignUpButtonView: View {
        var body: some View {
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                Text("Don't have an account?")
                    .scaledFont(name: "Gotham Light", size: 16)
                    .foregroundColor(Color("baydynamic"))
                Text("Sign Up")
                    .scaledFont(name: "Gotham Medium", size: 16)
                    .foregroundColor(Color("baydynamic"))
            }
        }
    }

    //Log In Button
    struct LogInButtonView: View {
        var body: some View {
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                Text("Already have an account?")
                    .scaledFont(name: "Gotham Light", size: 16)
                    .foregroundColor(Color("baydynamic"))
                Text("Log In")
                    .scaledFont(name: "Gotham Medium", size: 16)
                    .foregroundColor(Color("baydynamic"))
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Here is an example of how the `BottomTextButton` is being implemented:

```swift
HStack(alignment: .top) {
    VStack {
        if self.loginSignupScreen == .logIn {
            LoginView(
                loginSignupScreen: $loginSignupScreen,
                bottomTextButton: $bottomTextButton,
                loggedIn: $loggedIn,
                transitonBackward: $transitonBackward
            )} else if self.loginSignupScreen == .signUp {
                SignUpView(
                    loginSignupScreen: $loginSignupScreen, 
                    bottomTextButton: $bottomTextButton, 
                    signUpCTA: $signUpCTA, 
                    transitonBackward: $transitonBackward
                )}
            }
        }

VStack {
    BottomTextButton(
        loginSignupScreen: $loginSignupScreen,
        bottomTextButton: $bottomTextButton,
        signUpCTA: $signUpCTA,
        transitonBackward: $transitonBackward,
        buttonAccessibilityLabel: $buttonAccessibilityLabel
    )
}
```

Now, I am trying to dynamically alter the accessibility label but then I run into the error:

`Failed to synthesize event: Failed to scroll to visible (by AX action) Button, label: 'signUp', error: Error kAXErrorCannotComplete performing AXAction 2003 on element AX element pid: 4327, elementOrHash.elementID: 105553148256224.19`

Here is an example of how I am attempting to test this:

```swift
func testSignUpViewForm() {
    let loginBottomButton = app.buttons["logIn"]
    XCTAssertTrue(loginBottomButton.exists)
    loginBottomButton.tap()

    let signUpBottomButton = app.buttons["signUp"]
    XCTAssertTrue(signUpBottomButton.exists)
    signUpBottomButton.tap()

}
```

Comment: What do you need to achieve with your UI tests?

Comment: If you set the accessibility identifier instead of the accessibility label then this will have no user-facing impact, whereas accessibility labels only work in UI tests as a fallback since their primary use is to provide information to screen reader users.